# How create a barcode in Crystal Reports that appends a Colon :?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on creating a barcode in crystal reports that  appends two fields from a data table but I need them to be separated them with a ":". When I add the ":" to my formula its gives me an invalid barcode.

examples Field(job) + ":" + Field(part)

If I place the char value(58) of ":" by itself in the barcode it works and appending the 2 fields only (job) + (part) this works

However once I add in the ":" or the char(58) it does not work.

I also tried a formula with the barcode font however I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

What type of barcode.
That type might not support that character.

Comment: An BarcodeC39ASCII

Comment: Any thoughts how to get around that if that is the case ?

Comment: @user17312577 If a barcode type doesn't support a character, there is no work around.  The only option is to use a barcode type that supports the character.  However, I think you have a different issue here.  The colon is a supported character in Code 39 ASCII barcodes.  However, if you are you using a Code 39 barcode that isn't full ASCII, then this may be the issue.  I would double check your barcode font to ensure its really full ASCII before troubleshooting this further.

Answer (score 0):

":" is a valid character for that barcode.
I suspect one of the elements you are concatenating might be a NULL, resulting in a NULL for the whole expression.  Use IsNull() to test each of the components.

If that was not the problem, please provide more detail for how you are generating the barcode.

Comment: Well I figured it out, my elements were not null.However you do need to create this barcode using Code 39 Extended 3:1 which allows you to use all the ASCII Values and your barcode reader must have the capability of reading it not all barcode readers do that.